# Exception : The specified bucket does not exist - while Storing output in GCS (Sink) using Data Fusion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-data-fusion

I have a Data Fusion Pipeline that reads a GCS Bucket, do some transformation and then store the output (Sink) in another Cloud Storage Bucket. However, I am getting below exception when the Pipeline runs. I have granted Cloud Storage Admin role to Data Fusion Service account as well as the Dataproc service account.

```
2021-10-18 17:28:09,629 - WARN  [provisioning-task-1:i.c.c.r.s.c.DataprocUtils@88] - GCS path cdap-job/4f61e40e-3038-11ec-b538-e22acad5362e was not cleaned up for bucket gs://df-3070032220784195332-e6pu33jqaii6zerkaizbbqaaaa due to The specified bucket does not exist.. 
com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: The specified bucket does not exist.
```

Any pointer would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you figure out the fix?

Comment: Yes, this is fixed now. By Mistake, I have deleted the temporary and staging bucket created by dataproc. This was the reason for the above exception.

Comment: How did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

We can fix it by manually recreating the GCS bucket. I also made the same mistake and recreation of the bucket helped me to resolve it.